# How to configure Equinox to make it require optional packages declared in bundle dependencies

Tags: java, osgi, equinox

I would like to configure Equinox so that it throws an exception when starting modules which don't have all their optional dependencies available.
Just like with missing non-optional dependencies.
Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

This line added to satisfy StackOverflow's minimum character count.